# libstdc++ init with mingw

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, libstdc++

I'm working on a C++ library using mingw. However, as soon as I perform a function call that goes through the C++ runtime I obtain a sigsev (well, "access violation" proper, it is Windows). That makes me think that the initialization of C++ structures doesn't run. I would like any of the following:

1) Any concrete ideas about why this happens. Or otherwise:

2) Any hint about which functions in libstdc++ should execute for getting the runtime initialized.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please post the shortest compilable code that reproduces this behavior, along with how you compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the c++ initialization actually executes, but not in the correct order. I remember that somebody mentioned that getting the C++ initialization to run in the correct order is very hard, so I'm just taking a workaround. Thanks to those who read this question for  their time.